# Can we use Magnific Popup plugin to view .pdf files?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, magnific-popup

I'm using Magnific Popup plugin to view .pdf files. If file is image, it's working but if file is .pdf, how to achieve this? Following is the sample anchor with pdf file link.

```
<a href="https://test-qa.s3.amazonaws.com/34/239/expRepo/1785678479007_ProjectExpenseReport(Jan 1, 2014-Jan 24, 2014) (2).pdf?iframe=true&width=90%&height=100%" class="with-caption image-link" title="Click on image to enlarge/reduce it">Click here to open</a>
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you convert your pdf to image and dsplay the image? Perhaps it should be more simple

Comment: My pdf file may contain more number of pages. So requirement is load them as it is in a pop up if user clicks on provided link something like google docs.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

tried using the iframe for magnific popup?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.iframe-popup').magnificPopup({
        type: 'iframe'
    });
});
```

and open by

`<a class="iframe-popup" href="http://example.com/file.pdf">Open Iframe PDF</a>`

Comment: Iframe works for PDF as long as the browser supports it. Chrome, Safari, and Firefox all include native PDF support, but IE and Edge do not, according to this table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers

Comment: the iframe option does work for me in IE and Edge with a pdf file.
Edge does not display fancy "print" or "save" buttons but the file can be downloaded via right click. IE displays buttons on the bottom of the iframe. It still looks better in the other browsers but at least it does work in IE/Edge

Comment: @sidvishnoi How can I provide downloadable link if  browser does not support viewing pdf file, or not a valid pdf file?? Thanks

Comment: by using this: `<a class="iframe-popup" href="http://example.com/file.pdf">Open Iframe PDF</a>` ?